# gif animation with a transparent background

Tags: animation, gif, transparent

In matplotlib, I am trying to save a gif animation with a transparent background. I have tried this:

ani.save('tsk_julaug24.gif',writer='imagemagick',savefig_kwargs=dict(facecolor='w',transparent=True))

but could not get the transparent background.
Any hints to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following ImageMagick command lines solved the issue:

magick.exe mogrify -transparent white -fuzz 2%% in.gif
magick.exe in.gif -define trim:percent-background=0% out.gif

Comment: Inconsistent use of % and %%. In .bat file one needs to double the % to %%, but otherwise a single % is sufficient. Though doubling will not hurt.